# Как запустить exe файл вместе с его конфигом настроек?

Tags: c#

Мне понадобилось в проекте запускать стороннею программу, при ее запуске она подгружает настройки из конфига. Собственно вопрос, как мне запустить стороннею программу из моего проекта программно, чтобы еще подтягивался ее конфиг.файл?

Comment: Перед запуском поменять активную директорию на ту, что ожидает та программа, а это скорее всего папке программы

Comment: @gil9red, подскажите, пожалуйста. Если папка с программой находится на рабочем столе, в ней лежит программа и конфиг. Перед запуском я так понимаю, мне нужно что-то задать в Working Directory. Что мне там указать в моем случае? Спасибо

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо разобрался!)

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Напишите решение в ответе :)